# Unable to connect to Raspberry Pi via a Ethernet connection

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've purchased a RaspberryPi 3 B+, booted a NOOBS Raspbian and I've been trying to open a ssh connection via an Ethernet connection for the last couple of days. My goal is to be able to access the Pi via ssh while also sharing my Wifi connection to the Pi. My machine is running Ubuntu 18.04.01.

So far I've tried creating a new Profile for the Ethernet connection but without success. The only way the connection can be "successfully" created is by checking the "Link-Local Only" box, which will add "169.254.154.221" to my IP addresses. However, the Pi can't be found on the local network (pinging raspberrypi.local fails and an nmap scan doesn't return any good results).

Also, when I was first trying to connect the Pi, I was able to see it by executing "arp -a" in terminal, but now it is gone.

I've also tried connecting the Pi to my friend's Macbook and the Pi gets a local IP address, but it is still not possible to share the laptop's internet access to the Pi.

Comment: Why do you want to share the internet access of another computer with the pi? Why not let the pi have it's own internet access? Btw. do you have enabled ssh? Maybe this link helps you https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

Comment: Connecting the Pi to wireless is not possible without configuring the connection first and connecting it with an Ethernet cable to the router is not desirable, since I would like the Pi to be nearby the laptop. This is why I would like to be able to ssh into the Pi and have it access the internet without connecting it to a network on its own. And yes, ssh is enabled. As I've said in the post, I was able to connect to it using my friend's Macbook.

Comment: Then maybe your friends macbook did some kind of routing - which is required for such a setup. Btw. you could also use a small 4/5 Port switch (for 5 US$) nearby your computer to make 2 out of 1 ethernet cables.